# Mixins in Tapestry5

Tags: csrf, tapestry, mixins

I'm new to Tapestry5, but because of an internship I need to work with it.

Currently I am trying to build a mixin to integrate a CSRF token ([explanation here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)) to any form. Is it even possible to achieve this in a mixin? If yes, could I access functions that the mixin offers from the page?

I am really not sure about how mixins really work and I'm having big difficulties on finding information about how to create one. Can somebody explain how to create a mixin and if what I'm trying to do is even possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Some links:
http://tapestry.apache.org/component-mixins.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564743/how-exactly-does-tapestry-mixin-work

Comment: @sody thanks, for the links, but I'm more looking for some explanation on how to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that the [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) message authentication introduced in tapestry 5.3.6 is good enough. Configuration [here](http://tapestry.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-tapestry.hmacpassphrase) Jira [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-2008)

If not, you will most likely write a Form mixin which adds a hidden input to a form and then checks for a [RequestParameter](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/annotations/RequestParameter.html) in the form's `onValidate` event (a mixin can see it's component's events). If you want to implicitly add a mixin to every form, you can do this via a [ComponentClassTransformWorker2](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/transform/ComponentClassTransformWorker2.html) tutorial [here](http://tawus.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/tapestry-mixins-classtransformations/)

A bit of googling reveals [this](http://code.google.com/p/gsoc2011-csrf-protection/), [this](http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5CSRF) and [this](http://viennamarkus.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/to-get-in-touch-with-tapestry-internals.html).

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. 
On your last three links, I've already seen them, but I would really like to manage this on my on (you know, just for the learning effect)